# How to use UNTAR command in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, scripting

I want to replace `os.system` command with `subprocess.call` command in python.

```
D = "Some string value received at run time"
P = "Some string value received at run time"

Cmd = D + P + "| sudo /bin/tar -xvpPf - 1>> " + LoggerFile
untarCmd = os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system(Cmd))
```

Now I want to replace above `os.system` with `subprocess.call` command.

```
pCmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(D + P),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
untarCmd = subprocess.call(shlex.split("untarCmd"),shell=False,stdin=pCmd.stdout)
```

But receiving error

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
error writing output file
```

Comment: Hmm Ignore my previous comment. I think with `"Some string value received at run time"` you actually mean `"Some string value received at run time, that represents a command writing to stdout"`

Comment: Yes you got it..
But my command is not working with subprocess.call

Comment: I suggest, that you run first.
`fout = open("testfile", "wb")` and 
`pCmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(D + P),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and `fout.write(pCmd.read())` to see whether at least the first past is running correctly.

Comment: can you post one example (as realistic as possible, without causing confidentiality issues for your project) of `D + P`?

Perhaps `D + " " + P` could solve the issue?

Comment: Yes.

fileOpen = open(LoggerFile ,'w+')

cmdOne = "sudo /bin/tar -xvpPf - 1>> " + LoggerFile

pCmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(D + P),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


I've already tried with above mentioned open command but it's giving me same error

File "/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
error writing output file

Comment: I've tried this also:

 fileOpen = open(LoggerFile ,'w+') 

 cmdOne = "sudo /bin/tar -xvpPf - 1>> " + LoggerFile

pCmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(D + P),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

untarCmd = subprocess.call(shlex.split("cmdOne "),shell=False,stdin=pCmd.stdout)

fileOpen.close()

Comment: perhaps you add all the things you tried as separate code snippets to your question and you mention, which attempt gave which error message.

Reading code in comments is kind of a night mare

Comment: Can Anyone tell me What is meaning of below command?

Cmd = D + P + " | sudo /bin/tar -xvpPf - 1>> " + LoggerFile


What actually is getting untared?

Comment: in fact D + P seems to be a string representing a command. that executes and writes something to its stdout.

it seems, that this output shall be interpreted as tar file and be untarred as root. (Can be kind of dangerous depending on who created `D` and `P`) I guess D is a command and P are it's parameters. Please look at my suggestion to first try to run only `D + P` as subprocess and write it's output to a file.

Alternatively try tp print  the contents of `D + P` it might help understanding the issue.

Comment: How to use ontape command with subprocess.call with shell=False?

Comment: import subprocess
import shlex
Cmd1 = "/bin/gunzip -c abc.gz"
Cmd2 = "ontape -r -v -t STDIO"

pip = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(Cmd1),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    RC = os.WEXITSTATUS(subprocess.call(shlex.split(Cmd2),shell=False,stdin=pip.stdout))

Getting Error with Shell = False, It works when Shell= True

Comment: please add what you tried and code snippets to your original question. code snippets in comments are too difficult to read.